# How to reinit Windows Themes in Java Swing application running via RDP if Visual styles was disabled?

Tags: java, swing, rdp, windows-themes

I have a Swing application that is running on RDP sandbox. The RDP connection has option 'Visual styles' which is responsible for displaying or ignoring Windows themes.
First time I connect with the option checked and run my Swing application.
Then I disconnect and reconnect again with unchecked 'Visual styles' option.
And exception immediately occurs:

> ```
>     java.lang.AssertionError: part MENU.MP_POPUPCHECK is not defined
>     at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.XPStyle.getSkin(XPStyle.java:452)
>     at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsIconFactory$VistaMenuItemCheckIconFactory.getIconWidth(WindowsIconFactory.java:688)
>     at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel$1.createValue(WindowsLookAndFeel.java:1698)
>     at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel$XPValue.recursiveCreateValue(WindowsLookAndFeel.java:2382)
>     at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel$XPValue.getXPValue(WindowsLookAndFeel.java:2370)
>     at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel$XPValue.createValue(WindowsLookAndFeel.java:2357)
>     at javax.swing.UIDefaults.getFromHashtable(UIDefaults.java:231)
>     at javax.swing.UIDefaults.get(UIDefaults.java:161)
>     at javax.swing.MultiUIDefaults.get(MultiUIDefaults.java:64)
>     at javax.swing.UIManager.get(UIManager.java:955)
>     at sun.swing.MenuItemLayoutHelper.getMinTextOffset(MenuItemLayoutHelper.java:215)
>     at sun.swing.MenuItemLayoutHelper.reset(MenuItemLayoutHelper.java:138)
>     at sun.swing.MenuItemLayoutHelper.<init>(MenuItemLayoutHelper.java:107)
>     at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.paintMenuItem(BasicMenuItemUI.java:507)
> ```

As I figured out *`com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.XPStyle#getXP`* should return *`null`* if Windows themes are disabled but it doesn't.

The ThemeReader class does initialize UIDefaults successfully with native method *`sun.awt.windows.ThemeReader#initThemes`* but when it tries to get the theme it returns *`0`* because themes are disabled now.

So I think *`sun.awt.windows.ThemeReader#initThemes`* works incorrect in this case or may be there is any way to reset it hard?